# Why casting twice in this line?

Tags: c, casting

I've already read some Q&A concerning questions similar to mine, but I am still not sure if my case is the same as those questions.

I am wondering why we need two casts here: `(ULONG)(USHORT)(carry >> BITPERDGT)`

```
*sptr_l++ = (USHORT)(carry = (ULONG)*aptr_l++
                 + (ULONG)*bptr_l++ + (ULONG)(USHORT)(carry >> BITPERDGT));
```

ULONG : `typedef unsigned long ULONG;`

USHORT: `typedef unsigned short USHORT;`

C library used: FLINT

Book: Cryptogtaphy in C and C++

Comment: Because in cryptography, you want unreadable, obfuscated, **cryptic** code.

Comment: it'd effectively zero-out any "high" bits that are bigger than a ushort

Comment: Because we want USHORT mask a too big value of `carry ? But that's dirty. A mask would be a lot better.

Comment: @Amit: Only in bad implementations with obscure algorithms. Good cryptography does not require that (and the bad will be broken anyway).

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. Those types are not standard.

Comment: @Olaf - I was being sarcastic.

Comment: @Amit: Remember beginners might take such statements serious (or people not getting the joke;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to take OP's code piece by piece.

```
*sptr_l++ = (USHORT)(carry = (ULONG)*aptr_l++
                 + (ULONG)*bptr_l++ + (ULONG)(USHORT)(carry >> BITPERDGT));
```

This is somewhat simplified to

```
carry = (ULONG)*aptr_l++ + (ULONG)*bptr_l++ + (ULONG)(USHORT)(carry >> BITPERDGT);
*sptr_l++ = (USHORT)carry;
```

Given the range of `ULONG` >= range of `USHORT` and likely is *greater than* ...

`(USHORT)(carry >> BITPERDGT)` simple shifts the value of `carry` the least `BITPERDGT` significant bits out.  The remaining are cast with `(USHORT)` result in the most significant bits being zeroed.

Then code casts *unnecessarily* to `ULONG` with `(ULONG)(USHORT)(carry >> BITPERDGT));`.  It is not needed as the subsequent addition with a `ULONG` will cause `(USHORT)(carry >> BITPERDGT` to be promoted to `ULONG` even without the cast.

> Why casting twice in this line?

Although not *needed*, the `(ULONG)` cast may exist to emphasize to programmers that the result of `(USHORT)(carry >> BITPERDGT))` is promoted before the addition.

Answer (score 1):

The code appears to be part of a routine to compute the sum of two big integers (with digits represented as type `USHORT` == `unsigned short`, having `BITPERDGT` value bits each).  The cast to `USHORT` has the effect of discarding the high-order bits of its operand, but in fact if the converted result ever has a different value than the operand then the routine is broken (supposing that I have identified it correctly).

The subsequent cast to `ULONG` (== `unsigned long`) is not needed at all in this context, as the conversion it specifies would be performed anyway in order to compute the sum of that operand with the `ULONG` left-hand operand of the `+`.  In any case, it has no effect on the value, given that `unsigned long` must be able to represent all the values that `unsigned short` can represent.  Such a cast would only be *needed* in special contexts, such as to make a `printf()` argument have the correct type for its corresponding field specifier, or to widen the value to accommodate twiddling of its upper bits.